# compiler output (.class files) differs if sources were compiled in different directories

Tags: java, javac, bytecode

I have the following problem: While compiling some set of classes different .class files are generated if compilation was executed in different directories. The diff between generated .class files is following:

1) version:

```
1062: aload_3
1063: invokevirtual <some_method>
1066: goto 1078
1069: astore 15
1071: aload_3
1072: invokevirtual <some_method>
1075: aload 15
1077: athrow
1078: aload_3
1079: areturn
```

2) version:

```
1062: jsr 1076
1065: goto 1084
1068: astore 15
1070: jsr 1076
1073: aload 15
1075: athrow
1076: astore 16
1078: aload_3
1079: invokevirtual <some_method>
1082: ret 16
1084: aload_3
1085: areturn
```

Above code has the same execution logic. Unfortunately, I have to have explanation why the compiler behaves this way. What is strange, sometimes even when compiling in the same directory, the same sources, a difference between consecutive compilations occurs (always the same, mentioned above).

Any idea what happens?
Thanks in advance for response!

Comment: Are you compiling from the command line then? What are your javac calls?

Comment: Your methods are obviously too long if you have instruction numbers over thousand.

Comment: Which version (or better, versions) of the JDK are you using?  It looks like your second version was created with an older javac than the first one.

Comment: Also, for the next time: have a look at the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (the white question mark on orange ground).

Comment: This looks like the typical difference between the old implementation `finally { }` (using subroutines invoked via `jsr`) and the up-to-date implementation, duplicating the code (which seems to be the `aload_3; invokevirtual <some_method>;` sequence). In case of `javac`, the switch was made with Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

Does the class use any methods or classes which have package level scope?  This could account for any differences.

Comment: Why should this influence anything?